# Feature or bug: Workbox caches Google's analytics.js script, but it's an opaque response

Tags: workbox

I'm using workbox and Google Analytics in my PWA. I'm using the [GA support from workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-google-analytics) but as part of that, a cache route is setup for the `analytics.js` file.

That code lives here:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/v4.3.1/packages/workbox-google-analytics/initialize.mjs#L137. It uses the NetworkFirst strategy which will [allow caching opaque responses](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests#workbox_caches_opaque_response_sometimes).

The resource https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js doesn't seem to have CORS headers so we get an opaque response and as [the workbox doco](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/storage-quota#beware_of_opaque_responses) says:

> A common source of unexpectedly high quota usage is due to runtime caching of opaque responses...

This means my app will use 7mb of storage just because I have GA included. I can't tell if having the `analytics.js` file cached (a feature) is worth that 7mb penalty or if it's a bug.

I've opted out from workbox caching that script for me by using:

```
// make sure this it before the initialize() call so it take precedence
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /^https:\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/analytics.js/,
  new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly({}),
  'GET',
)
workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize()
```

...and instead hope that the browser disk cache will serve up `analytics.js` for me.

**Have I made the right call? Should I create a GitHub issue on the workbox repo about this?**

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant points:

First, the 7MB of quota that's used for an opaque response does not actually translate into disk space being used. Caching a large number of opaque responses can cause your origin to exceed the quota limitations imposed by the browser, but it does not translate into more bytes on disk. I personally would not spend time worrying about caching a single opaque response.

Second, it's the HTML document that loads the Google Analytics JavaScript which determines whether CORS is used when making the request for `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`.

`workbox-google-analytics` includes code that will intercept the `fetch` event for `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` and applies a caching strategy, but at the point that the `fetch` event is intercepted, `event.request.mode` is already going to be set to `'cors'` or `'no-cors'`.

If you want the request for `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` to be made using CORS, you can update your HTML to include the [`crossorigin` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes), like so:

```
<script crossorigin async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">
```

This assumes that the remote server actually supports CORS, which not all of them do. But that's the general approach to take.

(If [you're injecting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#the_javascript_measurement_snippet) the GA `<script>` tag into your page via JavaScript, then you'd need to call `setAttribute('crossorigin', '')` on the dynamically created script element.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff. I'm not worried about disk space usage, just the quota for my origin as my PWA supports taking photos that will count towards that usage.

I don't *think* CORS is available for that analytics.js script. Using the code snippet you provided results in a failed HTTP call with the error: `Access to script at 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js' from origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I know this isn't your jurisdiction though.